# Relationship between Markovianity and linear response function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, stochastic-processes, linear-systems

I consider a two level system interacting with a continuum of field. The Hamiltonian in Schrodinger picture, under the rotating wave approximation is:

$$H=-\hbar \omega_0 \sigma_z + \sum_k \hbar \omega_k a^{\dagger}_k a + \sum_k \hbar g_k ( a^{\dagger}_k \sigma_- + a_k \sigma_+).$$

In Gardiner & Collet, input output theory paper: https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.31.3761, they use this Hamiltonian to describe the dynamic of light field interacting with a system $S$ (a qubit in my example).

At some point they need an approximation of flat coupling to proceed, i.e $g_k \approx g$. They call it **the Markov approximation**.

A markovian dynamic is a dynamic in which there are no memory effect. In my own word, with handwavy approach, I would say that in this example, if the light field is cut, the qubit will directly process under its free evolution. He won't be aware there had a field just before.

---

What I would like to know is if there is a link between this and some aspect of classical linear response theory. Basically if I have an input $e(t)$, and an output $s(t)$, those two are related, if the system is linear by:

$$s(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{t} \chi(t-t') e(t') dt'.$$

On my basic understanding, if the system has no memory, I would expect the function $\chi(t-t')=\chi_0 \delta(t-t')$ (if I cut the input, the output is instantaneously cut).

It implies that $\chi(\omega)=\chi_0$: flat in frequency.

My questions:

Am I correct if I say that classically a system will be markovian if the linear responce function is a delta dirac as I wrote? If no, why isn't it true? It would mean the system will have some memory effect?

Is the Markov approximation made in Gardiner & Collet (and in many other places actually) physically related to this intuition?